# Click and Double click, deselect interaction OpenLayers 3

Tags: click, openlayers-3, double-click

I have tow **ol.interaction.Select**, one to the single click and the other one to double click.

```
var selectDoubleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
    multi: true,
    condition: ol.events.condition.doubleClick,
    style: function(feature) {
        //stuff here;
    }
    return feature;
}

selectDoubleClick.on('select',function(event) {
    //stuff here
}

var selectSingleClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
    multi: true,
    condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
    style: function(feature) {
        //stuff here
    }
    return feature;
}

selectSingleClick.on('select',function(event) {
    //stuff here
}
```

But when i want to deselect the double click, i have to click twice in the map. Is any way to deselect in double click with just one click?

Comment: You are assigning both to double click, and `return feature;` doesn't make sense where you placed it. Should it be inside the style function? We don't even know how your map looks like, so can you provide us a living example, in order for us to help you?

Comment: Yes thats true Icarus, my mistake, but the error continues. When i deselect the feature selected with double click i have to deselect with two clicks too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my version of resolve the problem i used some part of the code from @ahocevar
My solution is simple. First very if exists any getFeature link to this interaction (selectDoubleClick), and then clear this features.

```
var concludeClickEdit = function(eventListener) {
    if(selectDoubleClick.getFeatures().getLength() !== 0){
             selectDoubleClick.getFeatures().clear();
          }
}
```

Is better to have a event listening if the map was clicked and than clear the features.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do so by passing a custom function as `condition` of the `selectDoubleClick` interaction. Something that checks for selected features and reacts to double-click if no features are selected, and to single-click when there are selected features. Like this:

```
condition: function(mapBrowserEvent) {
  if (selectDoubleClick.getFeatures().getLength() == 0) {
    return mapBrowserEvent.type == 'dblclick';
  } else {
    return mapBrowserEvent.type == 'singleclick';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you verry mutch @ahocevar, but that way is not the very best to use, because we are reading allways the values from the map browser (mapBrowserEvent), is not the best way for me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the `mapBrowserEvent` is passed to the condition function by the interaction.

Comment: yes i know but didn't work that function. It was better to clear the feature that was selected by that interaction